# Docker Traefik TCP router HostSNI Not Working

Tags: docker, tcp, port, reverse-proxy, traefik

I'm doing my first StackOverFlow post because I don't know anyone around me to help me or answer my questions

explanation :
I have a vps ovh with 3 domain names that point to my vps server. On my vps I have 2 react sites and a game server my two sites are working perfectly. My problem is on the game server

I would like to be able to connect to my game server with one of my domain names just one I think my problem is with my HostSNI and TLS
When I have HostSNI(`*`) I can connect with all the domain names that point to my vps but when I want to connect with just one domain name but when I do HostSNI(`site.com`) I can't connect to the game server
If you have any ideas or have had the same problem please help me

Game server - Port used 30120 TCP / 30120 UDP :

[My Docker-compose of my game server](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jdGWW.png)

[My traefik.yml of my game server](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LCYAQ.png)

Answer (score 0):

i just figured out that HostSNI(`example.domain.com`) only works if the initiated connection is over TLS. And Minecraft does not use TLS so we are out of luck.

But there is some hope, you can configure SRV-Records to route subdomains, or else, to a specific port. Maybe you can automate this and voila!